# Basis, Spanning set, Linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused with the linear combination concept, see question below.

> Consider the three vectors $u = (5, -4, 7)$, $v=(2,-1,3)$ and $w=(-1,2-1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> Answer $\textbf{True or False}$ to each of the following statements AND briefly explain why it is True or False.
>
> a) $u$ is a linear combination of $v$ and $w$
>
> b) $\{u,v,w\}$ are linearly independent.
>
> c)  $\{u,v,w\}$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ .
>
> d) $span\{u,v,w\}$ forms a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ .
>
> e) $dim_\mathbb{R}\;( span\{u,v,w\} )=3$
>
> f) The following matrix is not invertible:
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}     5 &  2& -1\\ 
>        -4 &-1& 2\\ 
>         7  &3& -1\end{bmatrix}$$

My Try:

a)  I realised there were 3 equations:

$\quad2C_1 – C_2 = 5$

$\quad-C_1 + 2C_2 = -4$

$\quad3C_1 – C_2 = 7$

And when I used Gauss-Jordon, the matrix became inconsistent, so the answer is no,

b)  False as because, there was no solution and the equations did not solve to have the trivial solution

c)  I am not really sure what this means, in order for them to be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ does it mean they have to be linearly independent and because they aren’t. This statement is false?

d)  The spanning set of the three vectors forms a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, well they are not a linear combination of each other so I think this is false?

**e)    I have no idea,**

f)  True because if there is no solution the determinant = 0 and that means it is not invertible

Are my answers correct, and what is the answer to part e, please provide explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a$, you should have gotten the solution $c_1=2, c_2=-1$.

You're correct for $b$ and $c$. For $d$, note that the spanning set is going to have dimension $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$. We know it won't be $0$, and it can't be $3$ since $\{u,v,w\}$ isn't a basis for $\mathbb R^3$. Further, the spanning set doesn't have dimension $1$, since the vectors clearly do not fit on the same line (since, for example, $v$ is not a scalar multiple of $v$). Therefore, the span of these vectors forms a plane.

$e$ is false; if the dimension of the spanning set was $3$, then the spanning set would just be $\mathbb R^3$. Since there are only three vectors, this would mean that $\{u,v,w\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, which it isn't.

You're good for $f$.

Comment: What does it mean these vectors form a plane?

Comment: If you look at the set of all vectors of the form $au+bv+cw$ (that is, the span of $\{u,v,w\}$), it will look like a plane in $\mathbb R^3$. As an easier example, let $x = \{1,0,0\}, y=\{0,1,0\}$, and $z=\{0,0,0\}$. Then the span of $\{x,y,z\}$ is the $x-y$ plane, i.e. the vectors of the form $(a,b,0)$ where $a,b\in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

I will not write about this specific vectors, rather something I think is more important, and is that some of the questions are 'equal'-some of them are "iff" statements (actually all except 'd', since they can be linearly dependent but form a 2-dimensional field).
If you have 3 vectors for example, and they are all linearly independent, than the dimension of the span is 3, and they span $\mathbb R^3$, same goes for any number of vectors and dimension and $\mathbb R^n$ respectively.
This will help you with question 'e'.

If you need further help, write here in a comment and I'll explain.